# How to configure ILoggerFactory in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ilogger, iloggerfactory

In .NET 5 Startup.cs class there is Configure method which it's inside **ILoggerFactory** interface is injected. See below:

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            ..........

        }
```

In .NET 6 how can I get the ILoggerFactory after the *var app = builder.Build();* and call its **AddFile()** method to write logs like .NET 5 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like that:

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
   
 var loggerFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(ILoggerFactory));
    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Optimal Answer**

After installing `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` nuget package, writing below code:

```
app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Program.cs file, add the following code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// some initialization.
// example:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

// add logging
builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders(); // optional (clear providers already added)
    logging.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- In .Net 5, the Configure method inside Startup.cs is called after
  Service Provider is built. That is why the dependencies for the method
  are automatically resolved.
- In .Net 6, you need to add this code after the service provider is build as part of WebApplicationBuilder's build process.

Something like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
   var loggerFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

   loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");
}
```